# process synchronization shared memory edite in grid whith C

Tags: c

Please I have an EFP project and I stuck in a problem
 our project defined like this:

In a Grid was 2 type of process: process and m n Rabbits Foxes each process that moves random as the fox is to eat rabbits.

Pre-condition:
The grid is a shared memory between these processes
the grid contains NxN squares st chanque box can contain one and only one type (RABBIT, FOX, vacuum (anything))

to start and simplify things began to move only that n rabbits (without adding foxes) randomly in memory share (grid)

but the problem is that each process losqu'il moves (changes or modifies its old position and change the new position with a value [are number]) modifies the grid that was initialized at the beginning and do not connate the modification of another process. So it is as if there is a grid for each process

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>




typedef struct {
    int num_lapin;
    int posx,posy;
    struct cellule *next;

}Cellule;
struct sembuf buffer;

//Structure for initializing all the semaphores   
typedef union
{
  int valeur;
} semun_t;


typedef Cellule Lapin;


int **grille;//the grid (shared memory of the land)
int nbr=4; // nbr process
int x,y;// 
int semid;//id  semaphore 
Lapin *lapin;// Array of rabbits
int nbr_lapin = 0; // nbr rabbits initialized with 0
int pid; 



// creat grid
int** creation_grille(int** grille){

int i;
grille = malloc(nbr*sizeof(int**));

for(i=0;i<nbr;i++){
    grille[i] = malloc(nbr*sizeof(int*));
}

return grille;
   }

// Operation P
void p(int i){
    struct sembuf buffer;
    buffer.sem_num = i;
    buffer.sem_op = -1;
    buffer.sem_flg = 0;

    semop(semid, &buffer,1);

    }

// Operation V
void v(int i){
struct sembuf buffer;
buffer.sem_num = i;
buffer.sem_op = 1;
buffer.sem_flg = 0;

    semop(semid, &buffer,1);

}



//start init_grille()
int** init_grille(){

int i,j;

 int t[2] = {0,-1},taille=2; //  0 pour vide/ -1 pour lapin 

    //________________________________
    //INITIALIZING THE GRILLE With RABBITS 
    //________________________________

//START FOR
    for(i=0;i<nbr;i++){
        for(j=0;j<nbr;j++){
            int temp;
            temp = t[rand()%2];


                //%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                //if is RABBIT
                //%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
              if(temp == -1){
                if(nbr_lapin<=nbr*nbr*0.5){// 50% of rabbit in the grid


                 grille[i][j] = -1; //filling with rabbit


                    if(nbr_lapin==nbr*nbr*0.5) {//if it exceeds 50% 
                        t[1]=0;
                        taille--;}
                }

            }
            else   grille[i][j] = 0; //filling with empty
        }


}
//END FOR

return grille;

 }
 //END init_grille();


 //START Partagée la grille
 int partage_grille(key_t cle){

    int shmid;              //id of Shared memory

    // allocation Shared memory
      //%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

      shmid = shmget(cle,nbr*nbr*sizeof( int**),IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0666);
      if (shmid == -1)
        perror ("Problème creat Shared memory\n");
      else
        printf(" creat Shared memory\n");



    return shmid;
 }

 //END PARTAGE



//START AFFICHER la grille
 void afficher_grille(int numero,int ii,int jj,int** add){
int i,j;
system("\n\n");

printf("NUMERO %d \t PID %d  GRILLE %p \n",numero,pid,add);
for(i=0;i<nbr;i++){
    for(j=0;j<nbr;j++){
        if(i==ii && j==jj) printf(" #%d#\t",grille[i][j]);
        else
         printf("  %d \t",grille[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

    printf("\n\n");


   }
    //END AFFICHER




//START Creation du semaphore
int creat_sem(int size){
int i,erreur;
semun_t semun;

semid=semget(IPC_PRIVATE,1,IPC_CREAT|IPC_EXCL|0666);
if(semid==-1){
    printf("Mutex No Create");
    exit(-1);}

else printf(" Mutex  %d  is Creat \n",semid);

semun.valeur = 1;


    if (semctl(semid,0,SETVAL,semun) == -1){
        perror("Fatale Initialize Mutex\n") ;
        exit(1) ;
    }
   printf(" Mutex Inisialized \n");

return semid;

}
//END CREAT_SEM




//START initializing the array rabbits with position exists in the grid
Lapin* init_lapin(Lapin* lapin){
lapin = malloc(nbr*sizeof(Lapin));
int i,j; 

for(i=0;i<nbr;i++){
    for(j=0;j<nbr;j++){

        if(grille[i][j]==-1){
            lapin[nbr_lapin].posx=i;
            lapin[nbr_lapin].posy=j;
            lapin[nbr_lapin].num_lapin= nbr_lapin++;


            grille[i][j]=-1; // lapin

            }

    }
}

return lapin;
}
//END INIT_LAPIN





// START MOVE Rabbit
void deplacer_lapin(int num){



sleep(4);
printf("\n################################\n\n");
 srand(time(NULL));//initalize random

int t[3] = {-1,0,1};


 x = lapin[num].posx;// position X Current number "num" of rabbit 
 y = lapin[num].posy;//position Y



printf("Lapin AVANT %d a X-> %d\t Y-> %d   - %p \n",num,x,y,lapin);


x = x + t[rand()%3];//access a new position adjacent X rabbit number "num"
y = y + t[rand()%3];//access a new position adjacent X 


// x and y should not go out of the grid area 
if(x==-1)x=0;
else if(x==nbr)x=nbr-1;

if(y==-1)y=0;
else if(y==nbr)y=nbr-1;




    grille[lapin[num].posx][lapin[num].posy] = 0;//old value = empty




//Update rabbit"num"  position 
lapin[num].posx = x;
lapin[num].posy = y;


grille[x][y] = num; // new value = number rabbit




    printf("Lapin APRES %d a X-> %d\t Y-> %d         - %p\n",num,x,y,lapin);



    afficher_grille(num,x,y,grille);



}


// END DEPLACER


void traitement(int num){

while(1){

    p(0);
    deplacer_lapin(num);
    v(0);

   }
    }


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, id=1;
    key_t cle;
    pid = 0;
    cle=atoi(argv[0]) ;
   int  shmid =  partage_grille(cle);

//ATTACH The grid with a shared memory
     grille =shmat(shmid,0,0);
    if (grille== NULL)
        perror ("Problème shmat\n");
    else
        printf("shmat réussit\n");

 grille = creation_grille(grille);


    grille = init_grille();

lapin = init_lapin(lapin);


 afficher_grille(0,0,0,grille);

//creat semaphore
    semid = creat_sem(1);





                for(i=0;i<nbr;i++){

                    pid = fork();
                     if(pid!=0){

               traitement(i);

     }
     }

            //}

return 0;
}
```

for example unintended result:

3 rabbit process

-1: Rabbit / 0: empty / # # num: The number rabbit "nume" is here in this box maintenat

grid initialized:

```
 0  0  0  0
-1  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0
 0 -1  0 -1
```

---

process 1:
old position X 1 Y 0
position after X 0 Y 0

was in the process (1.0) is it to move (0,0) + the old box has become free (0)

```
#1# 0 0 0
 0  0 0 0
 0  0 0 0
 0 -1 0 -1
```

---

Process 2:
old position X 3 Y 3
position after X 3 Y 2

was in the process (3.3) is it to move (3,2) + the old box has become free (0)
1 but the process is in the box (1.0) as if there is no move

```
 0 0 0 0
-1 0 0 0
 0 0 0 #2#
 0 -1 0 0
```

---

Process 3:
old position X 3 Y 1
position after X 2 Y 1

was in the process (3.3) is it to move (3,2) + the old box has become free (0)
but the processes 1 and 2 are in their old box as if they are not move

```
 0  0  0  0
-1  0  0  0
 0 #3# 0  0
 0  0  0 -1
```

......

---

process 1:
old position X 0 Y 0
position after X 0 Y 1

process 1 to memorize its last change and moves it to another

```
 0 #1#  0  0
 0  0   0  0
 0  0   0  0
 0 -1   0 -1
```

etc ...

resulta wanted

grid initialized:

```
 0  0  0  0
-1  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0
 0 -1  0 -1
```

---

process 1:
old position X 1 Y 0
position after X 0 Y 0

process 1 to memorize its last modification and amendment of other

```
#1# 0 0 0
 0  0 0 0
 0  0 0 0
 0 -1 0 -1
```

---

Process 2:
old position X 3 Y 3
position after X 3 Y 2

process 2 to memorize its last modification and amendment of other

```
 1 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 # 2 #
 0 -1 0 0
```

---

Process 3:
old position X 3 Y 1
position after X 2 Y 1

process 3 to memorize its last modification and amendment of other

```
 1  0  0 0
 0  0  0 0
 0 #3# 0 2
 0  0  0 0
```

......

---

process 1:
old position X 0 Y 0
position after X 0 Y 1

process 1 to memorize its last change and moves it to another

0 #1# 0 0
 0  0  0 0
 0  0  3 2
 0  0  0 0

etc ...

Comment: I have edited my answer to present another solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: There is another solution, described in the bottom of this answer.

I tested your code, it seems you need to acceed data in shared memory using a one dimension array. For example:

```
int * grid;

for(i=0; i<nbr; i++)
  for(j=0; j<nbr; j++)
    grid[i*nbr + j] = 0;
```

You can have a look at this code, that seems to solve the problem you described:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>




typedef struct {
    int num_lapin;
    int posx,posy;
    //struct cellule *next;

}Cellule;
struct sembuf buffer;

//Structure for initializing all the semaphores   
typedef union
{
  int valeur;
} semun_t;


typedef Cellule Lapin;


int *grille;//the grid (shared memory of the land)
int nbr=4; // nbr process
int x,y;// 
int semid;//id  semaphore 
Lapin *lapin;// Array of rabbits
int nbr_lapin = 0; // nbr rabbits initialized with 0
int pid; 





// Operation P
void p(int i){
    struct sembuf buffer;
    buffer.sem_num = i;
    buffer.sem_op = -1;
    buffer.sem_flg = 0;

    semop(semid, &buffer,1);

    }

// Operation V
void v(int i){
struct sembuf buffer;
buffer.sem_num = i;
buffer.sem_op = 1;
buffer.sem_flg = 0;

    semop(semid, &buffer,1);

}



//start init_grille()
int* init_grille(){

int i,j;

 int t[2] = {0,-1},taille=2; //  0 pour vide/ -1 pour lapin 

    //________________________________
    //INITIALIZING THE GRILLE With RABBITS 
    //________________________________

//START FOR
    for(i=0;i<nbr;i++){
        for(j=0;j<nbr;j++){
            int temp;
            temp = t[rand()%2];


                //%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                //if is RABBIT
                //%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
              if(temp == -1){
                if(nbr_lapin<=nbr*nbr*0.5){// 50% of rabbit in the grid


                 grille[i*nbr+j] = -1; //filling with rabbit


                    if(nbr_lapin==nbr*nbr*0.5) {//if it exceeds 50% 
                        t[1]=0;
                        taille--;}
                }

            }
            else   grille[i*nbr+j] = 0; //filling with empty
        }


}
//END FOR

return grille;

 }
 //END init_grille();


 //START Partagée la grille
 int partage_grille(key_t cle){

    int shmid;              //id of Shared memory

    // allocation Shared memory
      //%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

      shmid = shmget(cle,nbr*nbr*sizeof( int),IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0666);
      if (shmid == -1)
        perror ("Problème creat Shared memory\n");
      else
        printf(" creat Shared memory\n");



    return shmid;
 }

 //END PARTAGE



//START AFFICHER la grille
 void afficher_grille(int numero,int ii,int jj,int* add){
int i,j;
system("\n\n");

printf("NUMERO %d \t PID %d  GRILLE %p \n",numero,pid,add);
for(i=0;i<nbr;i++){
    for(j=0;j<nbr;j++){
        if(i==ii && j==jj) printf(" #%d#\t",grille[i*nbr+j]);
        else
         printf("  %d \t",grille[i*nbr+j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

    printf("\n\n");


   }
    //END AFFICHER




//START Creation du semaphore
int creat_sem(int size){
int i,erreur;
semun_t semun;

semid=semget(IPC_PRIVATE,1,IPC_CREAT|IPC_EXCL|0666);
if(semid==-1){
    printf("Mutex No Create");
    exit(-1);}

else printf(" Mutex  %d  is Creat \n",semid);

semun.valeur = 1;


    if (semctl(semid,0,SETVAL,semun) == -1){
        perror("Fatale Initialize Mutex\n") ;
        exit(1) ;
    }
   printf(" Mutex Inisialized \n");

return semid;

}
//END CREAT_SEM




//START initializing the array rabbits with position exists in the grid
Lapin* init_lapin(Lapin* lapin){
lapin = malloc(nbr*sizeof(Lapin));
int i,j; 

for(i=0;i<nbr;i++){
    for(j=0;j<nbr;j++){

        if(grille[i*nbr+j]==-1){
            lapin[nbr_lapin].posx=i;
            lapin[nbr_lapin].posy=j;
            lapin[nbr_lapin].num_lapin= nbr_lapin++;


            grille[i*nbr+j]=-1; // lapin

            }

    }
}

return lapin;
}
//END INIT_LAPIN





// START MOVE Rabbit
void deplacer_lapin(int num){


sleep(4);
printf("\n################################\n\n");
 srand(time(NULL));//initalize random

int t[3] = {-1,0,1};


 x = lapin[num].posx;// position X Current number "num" of rabbit 
 y = lapin[num].posy;//position Y

printf("Lapin AVANT %d a X-> %d\t Y-> %d   - %p \n",num,x,y,lapin);


x = x + t[rand()%3];//access a new position adjacent X rabbit number "num"
y = y + t[rand()%3];//access a new position adjacent X 


// x and y should not go out of the grid area 
if(x==-1)x=0;
else if(x==nbr)x=nbr-1;

if(y==-1)y=0;
else if(y==nbr)y=nbr-1;

grille[lapin[num].posx*nbr + lapin[num].posy] = 0;//old value = empty

//Update rabbit"num"  position 
lapin[num].posx = x;
lapin[num].posy = y;


grille[x*nbr + y] = num; // new value = number rabbit

    printf("Lapin APRES %d a X-> %d\t Y-> %d         - %p\n",num,x,y,lapin);

    afficher_grille(num,x,y,grille);

}


// END DEPLACER


void traitement(int num){

while(1){

    p(0);
    deplacer_lapin(num);
    v(0);

   }
    }


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, id=1;
    key_t cle;
    pid = 0;
    cle=atoi(argv[0]) ;
   int  shmid =  partage_grille(cle);

//ATTACH The grid with a shared memory
     grille =shmat(shmid,0,0);
    if (grille== NULL)
        perror ("Problème shmat\n");
    else
        printf("shmat réussit\n");


    grille = init_grille();

lapin = init_lapin(lapin);


 afficher_grille(0,0,0,grille);

//creat semaphore
    semid = creat_sem(1);





                for(i=0;i<nbr;i++){

                    pid = fork();
                     if(pid!=0){

               traitement(i);

     }
     }

return 0;
}
```

You can also allocate a table of pointers `grille = malloc(nbr*sizeof(int*))`, and then allocate each `grille[i]` with `shmget()/shmat()`. You may also have to use `shmctl()` and `shmdt()` to deallocate shared memory or use a new key `cle` when you relaunch the program. Have a look at the following code, that use a grid like `grille[i][j]`, I have modified the functions `creation_grille()` and `partage_grille()`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>




typedef struct {
    int num_lapin;
    int posx,posy;
    struct cellule *next;

}Cellule;
struct sembuf buffer;

//Structure for initializing all the semaphores   
typedef union
{
  int valeur;
} semun_t;


typedef Cellule Lapin;


int **grille;//the grid (shared memory of the land)
int nbr=4; // nbr process
int x,y;// 
int semid;//id  semaphore 
Lapin *lapin;// Array of rabbits
int nbr_lapin = 0; // nbr rabbits initialized with 0
int pid; 



// creat grid
int** creation_grille(int** grille){

int i;
grille = malloc(nbr*sizeof(int*));

return grille;
}

// Operation P
void p(int i){
    struct sembuf buffer;
    buffer.sem_num = i;
    buffer.sem_op = -1;
    buffer.sem_flg = 0;

    semop(semid, &buffer,1);

    }

// Operation V
void v(int i){
struct sembuf buffer;
buffer.sem_num = i;
buffer.sem_op = 1;
buffer.sem_flg = 0;

    semop(semid, &buffer,1);

}



//start init_grille()
int** init_grille(){

int i,j;

 int t[2] = {0,-1},taille=2; //  0 pour vide/ -1 pour lapin 

    //________________________________
    //INITIALIZING THE GRILLE With RABBITS 
    //________________________________

//START FOR
    for(i=0;i<nbr;i++){
        for(j=0;j<nbr;j++){
            int temp;
            temp = t[rand()%2];


                //%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                //if is RABBIT
                //%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
              if(temp == -1){
                if(nbr_lapin<=nbr*nbr*0.5){// 50% of rabbit in the grid


                 grille[i][j] = -1; //filling with rabbit


                    if(nbr_lapin==nbr*nbr*0.5) {//if it exceeds 50% 
                        t[1]=0;
                        taille--;}
                }

            }
            else   grille[i][j] = 0; //filling with empty
        }


}
//END FOR

return grille;

 }
 //END init_grille();


 //START Partagée la grille
 int partage_grille(key_t cle){
int i;
    int shmid;              //id of Shared memory

    // allocation Shared memory
    //%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    for(i = 0; i < nbr; i++) {
      shmid = shmget(cle+i,nbr*sizeof( int),IPC_CREAT | 0666);
      if (shmid == -1)
        perror ("Problème creat Shared memory\n");
      else
        printf(" creat Shared memory\n");
      grille[i] = shmat(shmid,NULL,0);
      if(grille[i] == (int*)-1) perror("\nshmat"); else printf("\nshmat reussit\n");
    }
}

 //END PARTAGE



//START AFFICHER la grille
 void afficher_grille(int numero,int ii,int jj,int** add){
int i,j;
system("\n\n");

printf("NUMERO %d \t PID %d  GRILLE %p \n",numero,pid,add);
for(i=0;i<nbr;i++){
    for(j=0;j<nbr;j++){
        if(i==ii && j==jj) printf(" #%d#\t",grille[i][j]);
        else
         printf("  %d \t",grille[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

    printf("\n\n");


   }
    //END AFFICHER




//START Creation du semaphore
int creat_sem(int size){
int i,erreur;
semun_t semun;

semid=semget(IPC_PRIVATE,1,IPC_CREAT|IPC_EXCL|0666);
if(semid==-1){
    printf("Mutex No Create");
    exit(-1);}

else printf(" Mutex  %d  is Creat \n",semid);

semun.valeur = 1;


    if (semctl(semid,0,SETVAL,semun) == -1){
        perror("Fatale Initialize Mutex\n") ;
        exit(1) ;
    }
   printf(" Mutex Inisialized \n");

return semid;

}
//END CREAT_SEM




//START initializing the array rabbits with position exists in the grid
Lapin* init_lapin(Lapin* lapin){
lapin = malloc(nbr*sizeof(Lapin));
int i,j; 

for(i=0;i<nbr;i++){
    for(j=0;j<nbr;j++){

        if(grille[i][j]==-1){
            lapin[nbr_lapin].posx=i;
            lapin[nbr_lapin].posy=j;
            lapin[nbr_lapin].num_lapin= nbr_lapin++;


            grille[i][j]=-1; // lapin

            }

    }
}

return lapin;
}
//END INIT_LAPIN





// START MOVE Rabbit
void deplacer_lapin(int num){



sleep(4);
printf("\n################################\n\n");
 srand(time(NULL));//initalize random

int t[3] = {-1,0,1};


 x = lapin[num].posx;// position X Current number "num" of rabbit 
 y = lapin[num].posy;//position Y



printf("Lapin AVANT %d a X-> %d\t Y-> %d   - %p \n",num,x,y,lapin);


x = x + t[rand()%3];//access a new position adjacent X rabbit number "num"
y = y + t[rand()%3];//access a new position adjacent X 


// x and y should not go out of the grid area 
if(x==-1)x=0;
else if(x==nbr)x=nbr-1;

if(y==-1)y=0;
else if(y==nbr)y=nbr-1;




    grille[lapin[num].posx][lapin[num].posy] = 0;//old value = empty




//Update rabbit"num"  position 
lapin[num].posx = x;
lapin[num].posy = y;


grille[x][y] = num; // new value = number rabbit




    printf("Lapin APRES %d a X-> %d\t Y-> %d         - %p\n",num,x,y,lapin);



    afficher_grille(num,x,y,grille);



}


// END DEPLACER


void traitement(int num){

while(1){

    p(0);
    deplacer_lapin(num);
    v(0);

   }
    }


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, id=1;
    key_t cle;
    pid = 0;
    cle=atoi(argv[0]) ;

   grille = creation_grille(grille);
   int  shmid =  partage_grille(cle);


    grille = init_grille();

lapin = init_lapin(lapin);


 afficher_grille(0,0,0,grille);

//creat semaphore
    semid = creat_sem(1);





                for(i=0;i<nbr;i++){

                    pid = fork();
                     if(pid!=0){

               traitement(i);

     }
     }

            //}

return 0;
}
```